# Where to place Webmaster Tools HTML File on CRAFT CMS?

Tags: analytics

Im trying to setup my Web master tools for my site, but i'm not sure where to place the html file google provides:

[image: Web Master Tools]

[image: Craft Folder Structure]

I've tried the 5 main folders root but with no success. Also in the craft's root.

ANy advise on where should I put this code?

thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 2):

You should place it in your public folder (may have a different name on your server) not in your Craft folder. The folder where all files (such as your assets) live in that are publicly accessible on your webserver.